# com.chargeatfriends.android.ui.reserve.ReserveFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-navigation

I am developing new and when I run project I am getting following exception

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.chargeatfriends.android, PID: 31595
        androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.chargeatfriends.android.ui.reserve.ReserveFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
           com.chargeatfriends.android.ui.map.MapFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
            at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
            at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
            at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:615)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57) 
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$2.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:448) 
            at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:190) 
            at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:162) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateInternal(NavController.kt:260) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1719) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1545) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1472) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1454) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1437) 
            at com.chargeatfriends.android.ui.map.MapFragment.clickListener$lambda-0(MapFragment.kt:176) 
            at com.chargeatfriends.android.ui.map.MapFragment.$r8$lambda$f_HcQmFOF4yHY3eWCzm1TTIl2BA(Unknown Source:0) 
            at com.chargeatfriends.android.ui.map.MapFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2) 
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870) 
            at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970) 
           
         Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property sharedPref has not been initialized
            at com.chargeatfriends.android.ui.reserve.ReserveFragment.getSharedPref(ReserveFragment.kt:61)
            at com.chargeatfriends.android.ui.reserve.ReserveFragment.<init>(ReserveFragment.kt:97)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
            at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:615) 
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57) 
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$2.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:448) 
            at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:190) 
            at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:162) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateInternal(NavController.kt:260) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1719) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1545) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1472) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1454) 
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1437) 
            at com.chargeatfriends.android.ui.map.MapFragment.clickListener$lambda-0(MapFragment.kt:176) 
            at com.chargeatfriends.android.ui.map.MapFragment.$r8$lambda$f_HcQmFOF4yHY3eWCzm1TTIl2BA(Unknown Source:0) 
            at com.chargeatfriends.android.ui.map.MapFragment$
```

$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)

below my ReserveFragment.kt
code huge thats why shared as gist
https://gist.github.com/kyodgorbek/b78a0fa14f949baf9209b8ff5914aa02

below my MapFragment.kt when I click button I am getting exception above

val clickListener = View.OnClickListener { view ->

```
    when (view.getId()) {
        R.id.gotoBookingButton -> {
            sharedPref.CurrentChargePoint = CurrentChargePoint

            if (sharedPref.token.length > 0) {
                Log.d("@@@@@@@", "${sharedPref.token}: ")
                sharedPref.isAdhocBooking = false
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigation_reserve) // in this line


            } else {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigation_settings_login)
            }
        }
        R.id.mapView -> {
            StationInfo.isVisible = false
        }
        R.id.qrButton -> {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.activity_qr)
        }
    }
}
```

below my SharedPref.kt class where I am using SharedPreferences

below my ServerModule and SharedPref.kt class
https://gist.github.com/kyodgorbek/84f77dfd49a21066339053d5c6118883

what I have tried I tried following
[calling Fragment constructor caused an exception, kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176933/calling-fragment-constructor-caused-an-exception-kotlin)

all stackoverflow answers with simular problem and invalidate cache restart and debugged it as well not success any advices greatly appreciated

Comment: Have u initialized the sharedPref property before accesssing it?

Comment: yes I have initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in this variable

```
@Inject
lateinit var sharedPref:SharedPref
```

you are using it in this line

```
var EndTime: LocalTime = LocalTime.now().plusSeconds(3600 + sharedPref.defaultChargeTime)
```

check your dependency module if you are providing `SharedPref` class

Comment: Boudera what is your suggestion then

Comment: what is your suggestion then

Comment: show me your dependency injection module